# Mocha with co.wrap with generator arrow functions

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, ecmascript-6, co

I took an existing test:

```
it('should have a controller instance', co.wrap(function *() {
    stateController.should.be.a('object');
}));
```

and tried to use arrow syntax on the generator function and it the runtime complains

```
it('should have a controller instance', co.wrap(*() => {
    stateController.should.be.a('object');
}));
```

[image: Webstorm 11]

Comment: "The runtime complains." Maybe be a little more specific?

Comment: the syntax doesn't work the way I'm trying to do it.  If I'm in webstorm I get intellisense complaining

Comment: Of course, there seems to be no reason at all to use either `co.wrap`+generators or arrow functions for this test.

Comment: just makes it less verbose...And I had to use co-wrapt or else generators don't work with mocha

Comment: wtf, I know in the past I had this huge issue where I couldn't run mocha generator functions and someone told me to wrap it with co-wrap.  Now I take it out and it fing works without co-wrap, wtf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "generator arrow functions". It complains rightfully.
If you want generators, use generator functions (as expressions or declarations or methods).

Comment: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/generator-arrow-functions

Comment: I still needed co-wrap around my mocha and supertest integration tests